# Problem involving Dirac notation and Ehrenfest's theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, time-evolution

Ehrenfest's theorem in [one guise](http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/PHYS517/Ehrenfest.pdf) says (omitting hats for vectors) for suitable operators A

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\langle A\rangle~=~\bigg\langle\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}\bigg\rangle+\bigg\langle\frac{[A,H]}{i\hbar}\bigg\rangle\tag{1}$$

and an "[immediate" consequence](http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/PHYS517/Ehrenfest.pdf) is that, inserting the position operator x for A in the theorem, using P for the momentum operator,

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\langle x\rangle~=~\bigg\langle\frac{P}{m}\bigg\rangle.\tag{1a}$$

Ignoring the left side of (1) I reasoned (omitting test function in expectation values)

\begin{align}
\bigg\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\bigg\rangle + \bigg\langle\frac{[x,H]}{i\hbar}\bigg\rangle 
&=~\bigg\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\bigg\rangle + \bigg\langle\frac{xH-Hx}{i\hbar}\bigg\rangle \\
&=~\bigg\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\bigg\rangle + \bigg\langle\frac{xH}{i\hbar}\bigg\rangle~-~\bigg\langle\frac{Hx}{i\hbar}\bigg\rangle \\ 
&=~\bigg\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\bigg\rangle + \bigg\langle\frac{xH}{i\hbar}\bigg\rangle~-~\bigg\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\bigg\rangle 
\end{align}
and so

> $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\langle x\rangle~=~ \bigg\langle\frac{xH}{i\hbar}\bigg\rangle,\tag{2}$$

which I can convince myself is true.

On the other hand, using the first relation in this [problem set](http://web.mit.edu/3.23/www/pset3rev.pdf) (PDF):

$$[x,H]=\frac{i\hbar}{m}P, $$ we get immediately that

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\langle x\rangle~=~\bigg\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\bigg\rangle+\bigg\langle\frac{[x,H]}{i\hbar}\bigg\rangle$$

> $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\langle x\rangle~=~\bigg\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\bigg\rangle+\bigg\langle\frac{P}{m}\bigg\rangle\tag{3}$$

but then from (1a) that $\bigg\langle\partial x/\partial t\bigg\rangle~=0,$ which bothers me a little but doesn't seem to contradict anything above directly.

> My question is whether the conclusions (2), (3) in these two calculations are right and if not where I went astray.

Comment: Perhaps it would have been clearer if you *did* keep the operator hats on. $\partial \hat{x} / \partial t \equiv \hat{0}$ because the operator $\hat{x}$ has no explicit time dependence.

Comment: @jacob1729: I will go back and edit if it's too confusing. x is the operator throughout.

Comment: Note that you can use `\langle` and `\rangle` to get better looking bras and kets, instead of a bunch of less-than & greater-than symbols floating about.

Comment: @daniel My point was more that maybe its confusing you. $\hat{x}$ is a constant operator, not a dynamical variable (its not the position of anything) and so it doesn't have a partial time derivative.

Comment: @jacob1729, got it. I am just not used to taking time derivatives of position operators so it looks odd. If the conclusion is correct, so much the better.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Will go back and do this soon, thanks, and give out hats too.

Comment: I've edited the question adding right and left angles au lieu of greater than and smaller than signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that the term:
$$\bigg\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \bigg \rangle$$
Equals zero in the Schrödinger picture (which is the one you seem to be working with) because the operators in the Schrödinger picture are *constant*. That is, they don't depend explicitly on time. What *changes* in time is their *expected value*, and this is represented by:
$$\frac{d \langle x \rangle}{dt}$$
So one of your questions is answered (I believe).

Now, notice that:
$$[x,H] = \frac{1}{2m}\big(xp^2 - p^2x\big)$$
But $[x,p]=i\hbar$ so
$$ \frac{1}{2m}\big(xp^2 - p^2x\big) = \frac{1}{2m}\big(xpp - ppx\big) = \frac{1}{2m}\big((i\hbar+px)p - p(xp-i\hbar)\big)$$
And so
$$[x,H] = \frac{1}{2m}\big(i\hbar p + pxp - pxp + i\hbar p\big) = \frac{i\hbar p}{m}$$
It doesn't make much sense saying that
$$\bigg\langle\frac{Hx}{i\hbar}\bigg\rangle = \bigg\langle\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\bigg\rangle $$
As you seem to have done.

Comment: I will study this but in the four lines in which I break up  [x,H] can you tell me which one is wrong? (thanks)

Comment: It is the assumption you made from the 3rd to the 4th line, which I have stated in my answer (last equation).

Comment: The third full line is $\frac{d}{dt}<x>=<\partial x/\partial t>-<\partial x/\partial t>+<xH/ih> \implies \frac{d}{dt}<x> =~<xH/ih>$. If it's right, why doesn't the 4th line follow?

Comment: That’s not right. $\bigg\langle \frac{Hx}{i\hbar \bigg\rangle$ is *not* equal to the expectation value of the derivative of x wrt time.

Comment: Understood. So there must be a mistake in one of the previous lines. Can you tell me which one?

Comment: Look at the last equality in my answer. You used it in your calculations. And it is incorrect. That is the mistake.